# Событие при докрутке до блока на странице

Tags: javascript

Существует обычная html страница:
У нее несколько секций,

Нужна функция которая отслеживала бы событие скролла к блоку с id="about".
Когда срабатывает событие выводиться в консоль какой нибудь текст типа: console.log('yes');

Comment: а можно уточнить вопрос?

Comment: Вы дали верный ответ 
@ПростаMiha

Comment: Восстановил, я долго думал правильный ли ответ или нет )

Comment: Все верно, благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var test = document.getElementById('test');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (window.scrollY >= test.offsetTop - test.offsetHeight) console.log('yes');
})
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}

section{
  width: 100%;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: var(--c);
}
```

```html
<section style="--c: red">
</section>
<section style="--c: blue">
</section>
<section style="--c: green">
</section>
<section style="--c: yellow">
</section>
<section  style="--c: orange" id="test">
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо @ПростаMiha